# How to plot Choropleth map with folium and geoJson with a undentifed feature.id?

Tags: pandas, geojson, colormap, choropleth

I am following this guide to plot a choropleth map from Folium:
https://notebook.community/python-visualization/folium/examples/GeoJSON_and_choropleth

```
from branca.colormap import linear

colormap = linear.OrRd_03.scale(
    ecuador['Confirmed cases'].min(),
    ecuador['Confirmed cases'].max())

ecuador_dict=ecuador.set_index('Provinces')['Confirmed cases']

fec_map= folium.Map(zoom_start=6, tiles="OpenStreetMap", control_scale=True, location=[latitude_ec, longitude_ec])
folium.GeoJson(geojson_ec,
               name='Confirmed cases',
               style_function=lambda feature: {
                'fillColor'= colormap(ecuador_dict[features['properties.dpa_despro']]),
                'color': 'black',
                'weight': 2,
                'dashArray': '5, 5'}
                ).add_to(fec_map)
fec_map
```

GeoJSON:

```
geojson_ec = {'type': 'FeatureCollection',
        'features': [{'type': 'Feature',
                      'properties': {'id_prov': 1,
                                     'dpa_provin': '01',
                                     'dpa_despro': 'AZUAY',
                                     'dpa_valor': 0,
                                     'dpa_anio': '2012',
                                     'rei_codigo': '05',
                                     'ren_codigo': '01',
                                     'pee_codigo': '593',
                                     'codigo': 1,
                                     'codigo_1': 1,
                                     'nombre': 'AZUAY',
                                     'pob_mas': 337044,
                                     'pob_fem': 375083,
                                     'pob_tot': 712127,
                                     'si_lee': 591470,
                                     'no_lee': 51920,
                                     'total': 643390,
                                     'analfabeti': 6.7,
                                     'promedio_e': 9.01,
                                     'pobres_nbi': 338073,
                                     'no_pobres': 361875,
                                     'pob_nopob_': 699948,
                                     'densidad': 85.7,
                                     'edad_media': 28.85,
                                     'cartodb_id': 1,
                                     'created_at': '2015-04-20T23:35:12Z',
                                     'updated_at': '2015-04-21T16:01:08Z',
                                     }}]}
```

However, I am getting this Error:

```
File "<ipython-input-131-1cdbb903e2f9>", line 7
    'fillColor'= colormap(ecuador_dict[features['properties.dpa_despro']]),
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Please help me to understand the guide and to set the rigth colormap.

**VARIABLES:**

```
ecuador_dict=
Provinces
AZUAY                             10788.0
BOLÍVAR                            2120.0
CARCHI                             3080.0
CAÑAR                              2165.0
CHIMBORAZO                         2560.0
COTOPAXI                           4612.0
EL ORO                             6497.0
ESMERALDAS                         4324.0
GALÁPAGOS                           228.0
GUAYAS                            22588.0
IMBABURA                           4816.0
LOJA                               6375.0
LOS RÍOS                           4041.0
MANABÍ                            11464.0
MORONA SANTIAGO                    3015.0
NAPO                               1447.0
ORELLANA                           1972.0
PASTAZA                            2276.0
PICHINCHA                         60494.0
SANTA ELENA                        1796.0
SANTO DOMINGO DE LOS TSÁCHILAS     5322.0
SUCUMBÍOS                          2778.0
TUNGURAHUA                         6168.0
ZAMORA CHINCHIPE                   1582.0
Name: Confirmed cases, dtype: float64
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

10788.0
```

[image]

Solution proposed by – r-beginners:

```
fec_map= folium.Map(zoom_start=6, tiles="OpenStreetMap", control_scale=True, location=[latitude_ec, longitude_ec])
folium.GeoJson(geojson_ec,
               name='Confirmed cases',
               style_function=lambda feature: {
                'fillColor'= ecuador_dict[feature['properties']['dpa_despro']],
                'color': 'black',
                'weight': 2,
                'dashArray': '5, 5'}
                ).add_to(fec_map)
fec_map
```

Result:

File "", line 5
'fillColor'= ecuador_dict[feature['properties']['dpa_despro']],
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: To resolve the error, try to fix it like this.`style_function=lambda feature: {'fillColor': colormap(ecuador_dict[feature['properties']['dpa_despro']]`

Comment: Not working: File "<ipython-input-51-7d5edc7d5a4f>", line 5
    'fillColor'= colormap(ecuador_dict[feature['properties']['dpa_despro']]),
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: The corrections shown in the comments have been made and run with the data presented in your question. The question has been updated with the corrected data. Try running it with the corrected code. Please correct me if my correction is incorrect.

Comment: I added to the running and the error that shows me. I did not wor r-beginners. Please, help me.

Comment: There are a couple of issues: first, the geojson data is incorrectly specified. The second is that the `ecuador_dict` gets the value, and the third is that even if you get the fill color, the polygon data representing the 'AZUAY' region is not in 'geojson 'It is not in the.

Comment: In my environment, `colormap(ecuador_dict[geojson_ec['features'][0]['properties']['dpa_despro']])` gets the '#fed9b0ff' color.

Comment: I checked the updated question, but you have to be `fillcolor':colormap(ecuador_dict[...][]]` to get the color code, get the name of the city from geojson and Get the color code with the 'confirmed cases' number as the value of the color map.

Comment: I am trying to find out the value of the key_on

Comment: I haven't yet added the colormap to my choropleth map

Answer (score 0):

```
fec_map.choropleth(
        geo_data=geojson_ec,
        name='choropleth',
        data=ecuador,
        columns=['Provinces','Confirmed cases'],
        key_on='feature.properties.dpa_despro',
        fill_color='OrRd', 
        fill_opacity=0.5, 
        line_opacity=0.2,
                )

fec_map
```

[image]